# Is this substring safe in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, substring, strncpy

I need to extract a substring from a string with different length.
I would like to avoid using malloc.

Is this safe?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{   
    const char *PATTERN1 = "<Abcd.";
    const char *PATTERN2 = ">";
    const char *PATTERN3 = "<Fghi.";
    char *begin, *end;

    int len;
    char result[50];
    // lenght of toFind could be different i.e. "<Abcd.toGet>" or "<Abcd.toGettoGettoGet>" always less than 50
    char *toFind[50] = {"<Abcd.toGettoGet>","<Abcd.toGettoGetoGet>","<Abcd.toGet>"}; 
    
    int element = 3;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < element ; i++) {

    begin = strstr(toFind[i], PATTERN1);
    printf("Begin: %s \n", begin); 
    
    if (begin == NULL) {
        perror("Null begin\n");
    }
    
    begin += strlen(PATTERN1);
    printf("Begin2: %s \n", begin);
    end = strstr(begin, PATTERN2);
    printf("End: %s \n", end); 
    
    if (end == NULL) {
        perror("Null end\n");
    }
    len = end - begin;
    printf("Len: %d \n", len); 

    strncpy(result, begin, len);
    result[len] = '\0';
    
    printf("Result = %s\n",result);
    
    sleep(5);
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering if this could be a correct and safe way to do it in order to avoid segmentation fault, or memory corruption/leak.
Especially how *begin and *end it is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues that you need to fix.

1. Don't just carry on when `begin` or `end` is NULL.

You should add an `else` part where you place the code that follows. Example:

```
if (begin == NULL) {
    perror("Null begin\n");
} else {
    begin += strlen(PATTERN1);
    ...
    ...
    if (end == NULL) {
        perror("Null end\n");
    } else {
        len = end - begin;
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

2. Take of of writing `result`out of bounds.

The `result` array is fixed-size but `len` can get any size. So using `strncpy(result, begin, len);` will not protect you from out of bounds write. Add a check before using `strncpy`

3. Don't print strings if `strstr` returns NULL.

i.e.

```
begin = strstr(toFind[i], PATTERN1);
printf("Begin: %s \n", begin);   // Check for NULL **before** printing
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's terrible.

1. You use the result of `strstr` before checking for NULL. This is a bug.
2. You don't check that `len < sizeof(result)`, so the `strncpy` is dangerous. This is a bug.

   Using [`strncpy_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) would be safer if it were both available and well-implemented:

   ```
    errno_t error = strncpy_s(result, sizeof(result), begin, len);
   ```

   Apparently it isn't, so you need to correctly calculate the actual size yourself:

   ```
    size_t copylen = min(sizeof(result)-1, len);
    strncpy(result, begin, copylen);
    result[copylen] = '\0';
   ```

   (observe how easy it is to get off-by-one errors with this sort of code, and don't just take my word for it: check and test it yourself).

If you want to wrap this into a function, you can't use a local array variable and return it.

The only *easy* way to fetch a substring with no allocation is to actually return the (pointer,length) or (original pointer,offset,length) tuples.

Otherwise, you need the caller to pass in a result array (and the correct size!), and this just pushes the allocation elsewhere.

Comment: `strncpy_s()` is wildly non-portable and it's not any safer.

Comment: First, Annex K is **optional**.  And only Microsoft bothered to implement it - [**poorly**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations): "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ... **As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable.**"  Please don't invoke C11 to defend the use of `strncpy_s()`.

Comment: Understood. It's a shame there's not a better standard option, but thanks for clearing it up.